# Why we need to add the "ranges" when calculate ha_innobase::read_time?

Tags: c++, mysql

We see that MySQL needs to add the `ranges` when calculate the `ha_innobase::read_time` ([/storage/innobase/handler/ha_innobase.cc](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/storage/innobase/handler/ha_innodb.cc#L16552)), my question is why it need it?

```
double ha_innobase::read_time(
    uint    index,  /*!< in: key number */
    uint    ranges, /*!< in: how many ranges */
    ha_rows rows)   /*!< in: estimated number of rows in the ranges */
{
    ha_rows total_rows;

    if (index != table->s->primary_key) {
        /* Not clustered */
        return(handler::read_time(index, ranges, rows));
    }

    if (rows <= 2) {

        return((double) rows);
    }

    /* Assume that the read time is proportional to the scan time for all
    rows + at most one seek per range. */

    double  time_for_scan = scan_time();

    if ((total_rows = estimate_rows_upper_bound()) < rows) {

        return(time_for_scan);
    }

    return(ranges + (double) rows / (double) total_rows * time_for_scan);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This comment tells you the answer:

```
/* Assume that the read time is proportional to the scan time for all
rows + at most one seek per range. */
```

There is probably a seek for each range, and each seek increases the read time. Seeks were more costly on spinning storage devices, and most sites now use solid-state storage, but seeks are still a little bit costly. So it's important to count them when calculating the total read time.